# How to open dialog at particular a location?

Tags: android-layout, android-studio, dialog

I want to open my dialog box at a particular location in my app. I want my dialog box to be open just below my actionbar and not at the centre of my screen. Is it possible to do so? I want it to look like this.                                                                                    [image]

This is my Java code:

```
 Dialog game = new Dialog(MainActivity.this);
                game.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
                game.setContentView(R.layout.game_popup);
                game.show();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom dialog method:

```
public Dialog bottomDialog(Context context, int x, int y){
    Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);
    dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    WindowManager.LayoutParams wmlp = dialog.getWindow().getAttributes();
    wmlp.gravity = Gravity.BOTTOM;
    wmlp.x = x;
    wmlp.y = y;
    return dialog;
}
```

And then call it with:

```
 Dialog game = new bottomDialog(MainActivity.this);
 game.setContentView(R.layout.game_popup);
 game.show();
```